# A priority queue does not work well with compare()

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

I designed a priority Queue but it does not work for some test cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T1, class T2>
class priorityQueue {
private:
    vector<T1> dataContainer;

    class Compare {
    public:
    // Compare two elements .
        bool operator()(const T1& a, const T1& b) const {
        return a > b;
    }
    };

public:
    priorityQueue(vector<T1>& myV) : dataContainer(myV) {    
        make_heap(dataContainer.begin(), dataContainer.end(), Compare());
    }

    bool empty() const { return dataContainer.empty(); }
    // get the size of the queue 
    size_t size() const { return dataContainer.size(); }
    // get the element with the highest priority in the queue
    T1& top(){ return dataContainer.front();}
    // push an element into the qeueu 
    void enQueue(T1& element) {
        dataContainer.push_back(element);
        push_heap(dataContainer.begin(), dataContainer.end(), Compare());
    }
    // pop the element with the highest priority in the qeueu 
    void deQueue() {
        pop_heap(dataContainer.begin(), dataContainer.end(), Compare());
        dataContainer.erase(dataContainer.begin());
    }
    void printQ() {
        typename vector<T1>::iterator itr ; 
        cout << "the priorityQueue is : " << endl ;   
        for (itr = dataContainer.begin(); itr != dataContainer.end(); ++itr) {
            cout << *itr << "\t"; 
        }
        cout << endl ;      
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<int> aa;
    int a[4] = {5, 8, 3, 2};
    aa.assign(a, a+4);
    priorityQueue<int, bool> myQ(aa);  
    myQ.printQ(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

The compare class cannot change the priority ordering.

the output for `a > b` should be  `2  3  5  8`.

---

**UPDATE** The problem has been solved, thanks

Comment: What is the actual output? And in the question you use "a < b" but in the code you use "a > b", which one is it?

Comment: sorry, it is a typo, it should be a > b, output is 2 5 3 8. It can be run on linux, it should be 8 5 3 2 . thanks.

Comment: @user1002288 If you solve a problem, do not delete your entire question and replace it with text like "I solved it, thanks".  Questions and answers are here not only for solving your specific problem, but for people who come along later and might want to learn from them.  It's not possible to learn from an empty question; I've reverted to include your code.  If a problem is solved then either accept the answer of the person who helped you solve it, or provide your own answer and accept that instead...so please do one or the other.

Comment: @user1002288 You did it again (!) and I suggest you not do it that way a third time.  If you want to delete a question, you can click "delete" which serves as a *vote* to delete it...and whether that vote goes through or not is subject to moderation.  Please note that there's nothing special about being able to look back over the question history--it's like Wikipedia, it's all there unless you go through the deletion process.  You (or anyone else) can see the history too: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8337352/revisions

Comment: If the problem has been solved, then please accept an answer; if one of the provided answers is not the one that solved your problem then please write an answer that details how it was solved and accept that.

Answer (score 3):

In the `dequeue()` operation, you have to erase the *last* element:

```
 void deQueue()
 {
       pop_heap(dataContainer.begin(), dataContainer.end(), Compare());
       dataContainer.pop_back();
 }
```

Comment: After pop_heap(), the highest priority element is the first element of the vector , so the first one should be removed.

Comment: @user1002288: That's incorrect (see 25.4.6.2). *Before* `pop_heap()`, the largest element is at the front, but the entire purpose of the function is to move it to the back.

Comment: @user1002288: Try it with `std::greater<T1>()` instead (seems like that's what you're doing anyway).